# how to stop '...' being displayed as a question mark using php string replace

Tags: php, string

I'm working with stripslashes(),str_replace(), and htmlentities() right now. Whatever gets the job done.

One weird thing, the client has a pause in some text described with '...'. When it displays on the browser it displays as a question mark graphic. Does anyone know how to just display ...?  Can they please share the answer?

Example: Captain if we don't fight they...will kill us both.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $100 says your client does submit three dots, but a single ellipsis character. Make sure you got your encodings right at every point.

Comment: Hint: don't take that bet :^)

Answer (score 1):

It seems someone's using "..." as single unicode character. Try this:

```
$string = str_replace("…", "...", $string);
```

Your PHP file must be saved in Unicode to make it work properly.